# Is it possible top upload `react` app with `mysql` to `github`?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, github

I've made a siple web shop using `react`, `node` and `mysql`. I wanted to push it to `github`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to do that with database that's on my localhost right now?

Answer (score 0):

Git is a means to version control code.

There would be no problems storing your program's source code and your database schema (along with any migration scripts) in Git.

Storing the data from your database is another story. You would need to export it. Git isn't designed as a means of storing backups though.

Github also offers Github pages for hosting static sites. That service is not suitable for anything that involves server-side programming.

Comment: So is there another free way that my app can fetch data from database while on github? This is just a college project so that means not paying for any hosting etc.

Comment: Questions asking for product recommendations are off-topic because they tend to attract spam. If you want to find a free hosting service, then try a search engine.

Answer (score 0):

yes, check heroku.its free at some extend.
i have used it for my project, with mongodb.
heroku uses postgresql but there are ways to make your mysql working.
i think there are already questions about that.